# Model initialization

Tags: model

I have custom module named `Rkt_CustomBlock`. I am trying to connect it to the database. My table name is `socialcoupon`. My path of the module is `public_html/dev/app/code/local/Rkt/CustomBlock/Model`. what I want to know is what should i put in  `Rkt.php`. The xml declaration is working.

```
     <?php
class Rkt_customblock_Model_Mysql4_Rkt extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
     public function _construct()
     {
         $this->_init('rkt/socialcoupon', 'scid');
     }
}
```

I am confused about `$this->init`. what should i put in it? is it `rkt/rkt`? or something else

my config file

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Rkt_CustomBlock>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Rkt_CustomBlock>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <rkt_customblock>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Rkt_CustomBlock</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </rkt_customblock>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <rkt_customblock>
                    <file>rkt_customblock.xml</file>
                </rkt_customblock>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <rkt_customblock>
                <class>Rkt_CustomBlock_Block</class>
            </rkt_customblock>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <customblock>
                <class>rkt_customblock_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>customblock_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </customblock>
            <customblock_mysql4>
                <class>rkt_customblock_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <socialcoupon>
                        <table>socialcoupon</table>
                    </socialcoupon>

                </entities>
            </customblock_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <customblock_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>rkt_customblock</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </customblock_setup>
            <customblock_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </customblock_write>
            <customblock_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </customblock_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: show your config.xml file please ?

Comment: thats my config file.

Comment: what did you edit? i am confused

Comment: the codes are not aligned well. I just aligned it correctly :-)

Comment: Do you know what should be inside my model? I am little confused with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Magento you can call your custom entity `socialcoupon` in this way.

```
Mage::getModel('rkt_customblock/socialcoupon')->load(5); //this will load 
      //social coupon with id = 5;
```

This short code will load a socialcoupon item with an id = 5 from the database. Let us look how magento correctly "parse" your entity here.

General format : `Mage::getModel('[model_group_name]/[entity_name]')`.

In our case `model group name` is `rkt_customblock` and `entity name` is `socialcoupon`. Using `model group name`, magento will identify which module responsible for the specified model group name and then locate the model location folder. We are setting up these values via `config.xml`.

Similarly `socilacoupon` entity should also set up via `config.xml`. So your module should hold following model configuration.

File : `app/code/local/Rkt/CustomBlock/etc/config.xml`

```
   <models>
        <rkt_customblock> <!-- model group name -->
            <class>Rkt_CustomBlock_Model</class> <!-- model location indicator -->
            <resourceModel>rkt_customblock_resource</resourceModel>
        </rkt_customblock>
        <crkt_customblock_resource>
            <class>Rkt_CustomBlock_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <socialcoupon> <!-- entity name -->
                    <table>socialcoupon</table> <!-- table name -->
                </socialcoupon>
            </entities>
        </rkt_customblock_resource>
    </models>
```

Important points note to here are

1. `<rkt_customblock>` : this is the model group name. Rule for model group name is, ***it should be unique***. You have used `customblock`. There is no problem in that. But there is a huge chance to have that model group name is used by any other extension. So in order to avoid such conflicts, magento best practice says that, ***model group name should follow `namespace_modulename` format***. So in your case it would become `rkt_customblock`.
2. `<class />`: When magento called out by a particular model group name, then magento will look into this node in order to trace the model location for that module group name. Here we set this node with a value `Rkt_CustomBlock_Model`.Please note, those capitalizations in the value are very important here. This means magento now will look into `app/code/local/Rkt/CustomBlock/Model/` directory for all of your module's model classes.
3. `<resourcemodel />` : Resource models are used to communicate with the database. They are making real communication with database. When you call `Mage::getModel()`, magento will internally call `Mage::getResourceModel()`. This method uses configurations provided inside this node and hence it is very important to configure this node correctly. Here we are set `rkt_customblock_resource` to this node. You have used `customblock_mysql4`. You can use that value too. But ***[it is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491299/magento-difference-between-resource-and-mysql4)***. From `Magento 1.6`, magento follows the practice `[model_group_name]_resource`. So in our case, it would become `rkt_customblock_resource`.
4. `<rkt_customblock_resource />` : this node configuring resource model configuration. The name of this node is came from `<resourcemodel />` node. So when you call `Mage::getModel(rkt_customblock/[entityname])`, then magento will internally call the method `Mage::getResourceModel('rkt_customblock/[entityname]')`, which then eventually ends up in `<class />` node which comes inside `<rkt_customblock_resource />` node. This `<class />` node specifies where is resource model classes are residing. We set a value `Rkt_CustomBlock_Model_Resource` here. Capitalization is again very important here. According to this value, magento will look for resource model classes inside `app/code/local/Rkt/CustomBlock/Model/Resource/` directory.
5. `<entities />`: this is used to setup an entity inside our model. Here we setup `socialcoupon` entity. `<table />` node holds table name used by `socialcoupon` entity.

Now we studied model configuaration we needed. Now we need to setup `socialcoupon` entity and its resources inside module's mode section. Let us do that.

File Structure

```
rootdir
|________ app
        |________ code/local/Rkt/CustomBlock
                |________ etc
                |           - config.xml
                |________ Model
                        |   - Socialcoupon.php
                        |________ Resource
                                |   - Socialcoupon.php
                                |_________ Socialcoupon
                                                - Collection.php
```

First setup a folder structure like this (along with other files). Captitalizations are very important here.

### Entity Definition

File : `app\code\local\Rkt/CustomBlock/Model/Socialcoupon.php`

```
<?php
class Rkt_CustomBlock_Model_Socialcoupon extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        //follows the format [model_group_name]/[entity_name]
        $this->_init('rkt_customblock/socialcoupon');
    }
}
```

Calling to  `_init()` via `_construct()` method is very important. Every model entity should follow this format.

### Resource Model Entity Definition

File : `app\code\local\Rkt/CustomBlock/Model/Resource/Socialcoupon.php`

```
<?php
class Rkt_CustomBlock_Model_Resource_Socialcoupon extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        //follows the format [model_group_name]/[entity_name]
        $this->_init('rkt_customblock/socialcoupon', 'sc_id');
    }
}
```

***There are two types of models. `Flat Models` and `EAV Models`***. They are distinguished by reosurce model setup. What is these two types models is out of topic here. Here I am going to assume you want to setup a `Flat Model`. For flat models, your resourece model class should extend from `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`. This class is also contain `_construct()` class and it agains calls `_init()` method within it. But this time, an additional parameter passing. `sc_id` stands for the primary column of your table. Replace this paramter with your primary column name of your table.

### Resource Model Collection Entity Definition

Job is not over. By above your configuration, you can get a single item from your entity by calling

```
 Mage::getModel('rkt_customblock/socialcoupon)->load(1); //provided some data exist in table.
```

However if you want to get a collection of items, then you need to configure collection resource model for your entity. This is what we are going to do here.

File : `app\code\local\Rkt/CustomBlock/Model/Resource/Socialcoupon/Collection.php`

```
<?php
class Rkt_CustomBlock_Model_Resource_Socialcoupon_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        //follows the format [model_group_name]/[entity_name]
        $this->_init('rkt_customblock/socialcoupon');
    }
}
```

Main point note here is, this class extends from `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` and it also contains `_construct()` method as all other method does.

Now you are good to go clear your cache and tries to load your model with this call

```
 Mage::getModel('rkt_customblock/socialcoupon');
```

Hope that will help

Comment: Did you read my answer !!! ?

Comment: i was little confused about how to use getModel inside model. So if i want to load data in a form. can i use  $hh= Mage::getModel('rkt_customblock/socialcoupon');  and load by id. then echo it?

Comment: There is one thing i dont quiet understand. you didnt use core_read and core_write on config? i dont need it?

Comment: yes of course. you need to `print_r()` it because it is going to give you an object. It will give some error if you didnt configure your model correclty

Comment: Oh I fortgot to tell about that code snippet. it is optional as far as I know.If you didnt configure it, then magento will use default read write adapter. However magento best practices says that, it is good to include your own read/write adapter. So my answer for that question is, yes you need to use that code. But there is some error in your configuration. I will update my answer and let you know

Comment: `<module>Rkt_CustomBlock</module>` may work in your case.

Comment: I am getting this when i print_r  Rkt_CustomBlock_Model_Socialcoupon Object ( [_eventPrefix:protected] => core_abstract [_eventObject:protected] => object [_resourceName:protected] => rkt_customblock/socialcoupon

Comment: so now I can say you are in the right track. Magento is recongnizing your model entity as well as resource model entity now